# jquery ui spinner(can not initialize after ajax call)

Tags: php, jquery

I've stuck into a problem and couldn't find the solution.I am using jquery ui spinner in a shopping cart.onchange of spinner it has to update the cart with ajax call.First time it work well with all cart update but on second time it won't call.I reinitialized it but still not working.Here is my sample code

```
    $('.spinner').spinner({
    min: 0,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var get_row_id                = this.id;
        var get_row_value             = this.value;

            var temp                  = get_row_id.split('_');
            var row_id                = temp[1];
            var product_id            = temp[2];
            var checkout_flag         = $("#hidden_checkout_flag").val();
            var qty                   = $("#productqty_"+row_id+"_"+product_id).val();

            $.ajax
            ({
                type                  :"POST",
                url           : "client/cart/update_qty",
                data    :{'qty':qty,'product_id':product_id,'row_id':row_id}
                dataType    :'json',

                success function(msg)
                {
                    var value  = eval(msg);
                    $(".order_box").html(value.sidebar_content);
                    $(".landing_cart_content").html(value.cart_content);
                    $(".out_of_stock_error").html(value.out_of_stock_error);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".out_of_stock_error").slideUp();
                      }, 4000);
                      $( ".spinner" ).spinner();//reinitialize

                   }
              });

           }

         });
```

I have reinitialized it after  ajax call and onChange of spinner it should again call the 'update_cart' function but it's not doing that. I've already wasted a whole day to solve this bit still no luck.

Any help will be highly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at browser console if there's any error?

Comment: thanks for your response.I checked my console and nothing was there.Actually it failed to make call to the controller